# Python add value to dictionary item

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like below.

```
inventory = {
    'gold' : 500,
    'pouch' : ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'], # Assigned a new list to 'pouch' key
    'backpack' : ['xylophone','dagger', 'bedroll','bread loaf']
}
```

How to add 50 to the number stored under the 'gold' key?

Comment: `inventory['gold'] += 50`

Comment: I don't see why the question was downvoted so much. It may be very basic to many, but it is a legitimate and well posed question.

Comment: you may want to look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) before using a dict since it is good to know how it works before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

As told in the comments:

```
inventory['gold'] += 50
```

Answer (score 1):

`inventory['gold']` will get you the value of `'gold'` key. So if you want to add 50 to that value then just simply write `inventory['gold'] += 50`.